# Holomorphic function from the unit ball to the unit square

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f$ be a bijective holomorphic function from the unit ball
$
D(0,1)=
\{
z\in\mathbb{C}^2:\vert z\vert \leq 1
\}
$
to the square 
$Q
=
\{
z=(x+iy)\in\mathbb{C}^2:\vert x\vert \leq 1,\vert y\vert \leq 1
\}
$.

The I would to prove that for all $z\in D(0,1)$, $f(iz)=if(z)$.

I am currently clueless on how to proceed. I guess I have to use Cauchy's formula somehow.
All I know, is that the function $h(z)=f(z)-\frac{f(iz)}{i}$ cannot be injective and $h(0)$ and
$h'(0)$.(To show that is not injective, use a conformal mapping $\varphi$ from $D(0,1)$ to $D(0,1)$
so that $\varphi(0)=0$, then $(\varphi\circ h)'(0)=0$, and since $\varphi$ is biholomorphic,
it must be that $h$ is not injective )

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Prove that a bijective holomorphic function is conformal. Conformal functions preserve angles and orientation. Now, look at $z$ and $iz$ and their images under $f$. Can you continue?

Comment: I swear, when I saw your answer I facepalmed. Thank you!